# VB.net using google translator

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i tried to translate the word "test",

my code:

```
Imports Google.API.Translate

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = "test"
        Dim gtras As New TranslateClient("MY API KEY")
        Label1.Text = gtras.Translate(TextBox1.Text, Language.English, Language.Hebrew, TranslateFormat.Text)

    End Sub
End Class
```

the exception is:

```
Attempt by method 'Google_Translator.Form1.Button1_Click(System.Object, System.EventArgs)' to access method 'Google.API.Enumeration.op_Implicit(Google.API.Enumeration)' failed.
```

Comment: It sounds like the path to the Google API isn't set up correctly. Honestly, this is just a guess (hence being a comment, and not a suggested answer).

Comment: Also, be sure the .Net version your project is targeting matches the .Net version of the Google API you are using.

Comment: @sacredfaith why would changing the .Net framework make a difference?

Comment: Bugs, functionality, and possibly, backwards compatibility. For example, the API might utilize things in a later framework version that did not exist in a previous version.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in a later version of the API (0.3.1 seems to work):

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/issues/detail?id=43

Answer (score 0):

This code works very well:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Web
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox(gtranslate(TextBox1.Text, "it", "en"))'From italian to english, of course you can change it
End Sub

Public Shared Function gtranslate(ByVal inputtext As String, ByVal fromlangid As String, ByVal tolangid As String) As String
    inputtext = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(inputtext)
    Dim step1 As New WebClient
    Dim step2 As String = step1.DownloadString("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=" & tolangid & "&hl=" & fromlangid & "&dt=t&dt=bd&dj=1&source=icon&q=" & inputtext)
    Dim step3 As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = JObject.Parse(step2)
    Dim step4 As String = step3.SelectToken("sentences[0]").SelectToken("trans").ToString()
    Return step4
End Function
End Class
```

The dll library "Newtonsoft.JSON" is available from [their website](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and, if you get some errors with "HttpUtility", add the reference "System.Web" in the add reference window -> .net tab

Answer (score 0):

Fix Encoding And update code

```
Public Shared Function gtranslate(ByVal inputtext As String, ByVal fromlangid As String, ByVal tolangid As String) As String
    inputtext = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(inputtext)
    Dim step1 As New WebClient
    step1.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    Dim step2 As String = step1.DownloadString("https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=" & tolangid & "&hl=" & fromlangid & "&dt=t&dt=bd&dj=1&source=icon&q=" & inputtext)
    Dim step3 As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = JObject.Parse(step2)
    Dim step4 As String = step3.SelectToken("sentences[0]").SelectToken("trans").ToString()

    Return step4


End Function
```

Add : **step1.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8**